# Unable to mock the return value of the private method in python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have the core logic as below:

```
class DBTProjectUploader:
    def __init__(self, file_manager: FileManager, s3_client):
        self.file_manager = file_manager
        self.s3_client = s3_client

    def copy(self, dbt_attr: DbtAttr):
        old_bucket, old_bucket_name, old_prefix, new_bucket, new_prefix = self.__get_bucket_name_and_prefixes(dbt_attr)
        for f in self.file_manager.list_objects(old_bucket, old_prefix):
            old_source = {'Bucket': old_bucket_name, 'Key': f.key}
            new_key = f.key.replace(old_prefix, new_prefix, 1)
            self.file_manager.copy_object(new_bucket, new_key, old_source)
        return "Success"

    def __get_bucket_name_and_prefixes(self, dbt_attr: DbtAttr):
        old_bucket_name, old_prefix = self.__get_bucket_and_key(dbt_attr.dag_file_location)
        new_bucket_name, new_prefix = self.__get_bucket_and_key("s3://" + old_bucket_name + "/dags/dbt/")
        old_bucket = self.s3_client.Bucket(old_bucket_name)
        new_bucket = self.s3_client.Bucket(new_bucket_name)
        return old_bucket, old_bucket_name, old_prefix, new_bucket, new_prefix

    def __get_bucket_and_key(self, path: str):
        return path[5:].split('/', 1)

class FileManager:
    logger = get_provisioner_logger()

    def __init__(self, s3_client):
        self.s3_client = s3_client
    
    def list_objects(self, old_bucket, old_prefix):
        return old_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=old_prefix)

    def copy_object(self, new_bucket, new_key, old_source):
        new_obj = new_bucket.Object(new_key)
        new_obj.copy(old_source)
        return "Success"
```

Where the `DBTProjectUploader.copy` is responsible for copying the `S3` nested objects from one path to another path. Now, I am trying to write the test case using the `Python unit test` for the `copy` method. However, I am unable to mock the value returned from the private method due to which I am getting the mock id in the return value.

```
def mock_s3_object(self, key, body):
        obj = MagicMock()
        obj.key = key
        obj.get.return_value = {'Body': MagicMock(read=MagicMock(return_value=body))}
        return obj



 @patch('boto3.resource')
    @patch('provisioner.src.services.dbt_project_uploader.DBTProjectUploader._DBTProjectUploader__get_bucket_name_and_prefixes',
        return_value="bucket-name")
    def test_upload_dbt_project(self, mock_resource, mock_get_bucket_name_and_prefixes):
        source_bucket = MagicMock()
        dest_bucket = MagicMock()
        mock_s3_client = MagicMock()
        file_manager = MagicMock()

        dbt_attr = DbtAttr("path", "s3://bucket-name/old-prefix/", "dbt_mwaa01")

        mock_resource.Bucket.side_effect = [source_bucket, dest_bucket]
        print(source_bucket)

        source_bucket.objects.filter.return_value = [
            self.mock_s3_object('new_prefix/dags/dbt/dbt_mwaa01/', b'Sample data')
        ]

        uploader = DBTProjectUploader(file_manager, mock_s3_client)
        result = uploader.copy(dbt_attr)

        file_manager.list_objects.assert_called_once_with('bucket-name', "old-prefix/")
        # source_bucket.objects.filter.assert_called_once_with("old-prefix/")
        dest_bucket.Object.assert_called_once_with('new_prefix/dags/dbt/dbt_mwaa01/')
        dest_bucket.Object.return_value.copy.assert_called_once_with(
            {'Bucket': 'bucket-name', 'Key': 'new_prefix/dags/dbt/dbt_mwaa01/'})

        self.assertEqual(result, 'Success')
```

It gives an error below:

```
Expected: list_objects('bucket-name', 'old-prefix/')
Actual: list_objects(<MagicMock name='mock.Bucket()' id='4572034384'>, 'old-prefix/')
```

I have already tried to mock the private method but when I try to print the variables inside the original methods, it gives mock-ids only. It doesn't return the value. What else am I missing here? TIA

Answer (score 0):

note that `__get_bucket_name_and_prefixes` method is private,
it is called by the `copy` method, it wasnt mocked properly in your test.
Therefore, it is returning a mock object instead of the expected values, which is causing the failure in the test.

try

```
@patch('boto3.resource')
def test_upload_dbt_project(self, mock_resource):
    source_bucket = MagicMock()
    dest_bucket = MagicMock()
    mock_s3_client = MagicMock()
    file_manager = FileManager(mock_s3_client)

    dbt_attr = DbtAttr("path", "s3://bucket-name/old-prefix/", "dbt_mwaa01")

    mock_resource.return_value.Bucket.side_effect = [source_bucket, dest_bucket]
    mock_resource.return_value.meta.client.head_bucket.side_effect = botocore.exceptions.ClientError(
        {'Error': {'Code': '404', 'Message': 'Not Found'}},
        'HeadBucket'
    )

    source_bucket.objects.filter.return_value = [
        self.mock_s3_object('new_prefix/dags/dbt/dbt_mwaa01/', b'Sample data')
    ]

    with patch.object(DBTProjectUploader, '_DBTProjectUploader__get_bucket_name_and_prefixes') as mock_get_bucket_name_and_prefixes:
        mock_get_bucket_name_and_prefixes.return_value = (source_bucket, 'bucket-name', 'old-prefix', dest_bucket, 'new_prefix/')
        uploader = DBTProjectUploader(file_manager, mock_s3_client)
        result = uploader.copy(dbt_attr)

    file_manager.list_objects.assert_called_once_with(source_bucket, "old-prefix")
    source_bucket.objects.filter.assert_called_once_with(Prefix="old-prefix")
    dest_bucket.Object.assert_called_once_with('new_prefix/dags/dbt/dbt_mwaa01/')
    dest_bucket.Object.return_value.copy.assert_called_once_with(
        {'Bucket': 'bucket-name', 'Key': 'new_prefix/dags/dbt/dbt_mwaa01/'})

    self.assertEqual(result, 'Success')
```